# What do I return if there is no numerical solution for my int returning method to find?

Tags: java, int, return

This is my method for finding a single duplicate within an array. What should I return when an array has no duplicates?

```
public int findDuplicate(int[] array) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
    int duplicate = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == duplicate)
        {
            return duplicate;
        }
        duplicate = array[i];
    }
    return ???;
}
```

Comment: You could have it return an `Integer` (and thus return NULL) instead of a raw type. Or have it throw an exception.

Comment: You should split this into two methods -- Has duplicate and find duplicate. Also keep in mind this sorts the original array as arrays as passed by referance.

Comment: usually `-1` is a good option

Comment: -1 is what I'd normally go for. Especially as the arrays I'm dealing with only have positive numbers within them but it feels sloppy having a method incapable of handling negative numbers should the need arise.

Comment: return index, not value

Comment: and, as mentioned, making manipulations to mutable argument in method, which purpose is to make another task, is not good idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three possible solutions come to mind:

1. Return the matching index or -1 if there is no duplicate. You can't return -1 if you return the duplicate value because it may be -1.
2. Use `Integer` and return `null`. I don't like that kind of APIs personally.
3. Split your method in `boolean hasDuplicate()` and `int getDuplicate()` and throw an exception if there is no duplicate. This feels wrong, because raising an exception because everything is fine is quite odd.

You might want to change some details of your code, too:

- Copy the array before you sort it, so the callers stuff won't be modified
- Document the corner cases. Which duplicate is found? The first? The last?

Comment: If you return `Integer` and somewhere accidentally  assign value to `int`, compiler won't complain because of autounboxing, but the program will have a chance to crush with NullPointerException...

Comment: That's why (quote) **I don't like that kind of APIs personally.**

Answer (score 2):

Generate and return *array* of duplicated values. If it has zero size, then no duplicates were found.

Comment: Good idea, but I think the information which indices are duplicates/duplicated should not be lost. A map with `index => value` would be nicer.

Comment: @atamanroman author is already altering initial array, so I believe he doesn't care about index information :)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three possible solutions:

1. You can either return a value that the method should never return under normal circumstances, such as `-1` in your case.
2. You can change the return type to `Integer` and return a `null`. Automatic boxing and unboxing can simplify the work needed to make this change.
3. You can throw an exception.

Comment: Returning -1 would be wrong in this particular case, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

-1 is the best option. Or add another method for detecting if there is a duplicate in an array or not.

Comment: What happens with `[-1, -1, 1, 2, 3]` ?